# LaTeX symbols for physics

Tags: support

I realised that a bunch of LaTeX symbols actually cannot be used in stackexchange, for example

$$\right)$$ gives me nothing...

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 5):

Pair it with a left parenthesis? :-P

```
$$\left( stuff \right)$$
```

While this *particular* piece of LaTeX syntax is supported if you use it correctly, there are many others that are not. The system this site uses for typesetting math is [MathJaX](http://www.mathjax.org/), which implements a set of commands that correspond to a subset of LaTeX syntax. You can see which commands are supported in the [MathJaX documentation](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/). As a general rule, if you try to do anything especially tricky that would work in LaTeX, don't count on it working in MathJaX, but the simple stuff should be fine.